# Running multiple executables from a windows service

Tags: windows-services

I would like to achieve the following. I have a C# server application which is run by a Windows Service. The service currently requires that the server application is located in a specific directory.

Is it possible to create a Windows Service that takes a directory at start and run the application in that directory? How do you do that?

Can such a "configurable" service be used to start multiple application (executables with same name but located in different directories). This would be used to run different versions of a server application in parallel. Or do you need one service per running instance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply set the context to reflect the desired environment.To do this use [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x.aspx).
A single service can start many applications, each with its environment. Use a configuration file or persistent data in the registry.